# Removing a single quotes from an output tuple

Tags: python, formatting, tuples

I'm working to create a tuple in Python in the following way:

```
tuple = (the_schema['fields'][i]['name'],the_schema['fields'][i]['type'])
```

and am getting the output `('stn', 'str')`.

My desired output is `('stn', str)`, where the second element of the tuple doesn't have the single quotes.

When I print `(the_schema['fields'][i]['type'])`, I get `str` as desired. The issue, as I understand, is that Python automatically formats the tuple with quotations. How can I remove the quotation? I have tried the `.replace()` and `.strip()` methods, as well as something similar to `",".join([str(s) for s in list(k)])`.

Comment: The tuple doesn't have quotes in it; the *string representation* of the tuple contains the string representation of the strings. You should build your own string instead of simply letting `str(tuple)` create one for you.

Comment: If you have indeed `str` as `the_schema['fields'][i]['type']`, printing the tuple should give you `('some_name', <class 'str'>)` which as @chepner mentioned is just the `repr` of the `str` type, meaning the second element of the tuple is indeed `str` it is just shown as a string when you print the whole tuple

Comment: @re-za I think he has two string values; he wants `something(('foo', 'bar')) == "('foo', bar)"`.

Comment: Oh I guess I took the `type` key too seriously. In that case the provided answer below would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From python 3.6 on, you can use f-strings to create strings using variables, and that is quite easy to do.

Here, for your output you could use:

```py
string_tuple = f"('{the_schema['fields'][i]['name']}', {the_schema['fields'][i]['type']})"
```

Comment: this helps! However, when I append the ```string_tuple``` into a dictionary, it creates an output such as ```["('stn', str)", "('wban', str)"]```. Is there any way to get rid of the extra double quotes from each tuple so that the output would be ```[('stn',str),('wban',str)]```?

Comment: The double quotes aren't "in" anything; they are just the representation of the *string* (not tuple) when you convert the list to a string. Just like you turn the tuple into a custom string, you should turn the list into a custom string as well, not just use `print(some_list)`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Should have clarified earlier, but is there an easy way to easily convert this back into a dictionary/tuple or append the ```string_tuple``` into a dictionary, as I want to pass in the output of this into a function that takes in a dictionary/tuple. If I understand correctly, the proposed approach will lead to a custom string ```[('stn',str),('wban',str)]``` that would be of type ```string``` and not ```list```